# Smooth croll to anchor with scroll-behavior, but 100px above

Tags: javascript, html, css, scroll

I'm  trying to do smooth scroll effect to anchors on my page, but i need to scroll it 100px above because of sticky header. Don't want to use JQuery there.
I have tried to add pseudoclass to block with anchor like this:

```
div:target:before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  height: 100px;
  margin-top: -100px;
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

This didn't work, it overlaying block above.
Then i've tried to scroll it by event listener:

```
window.addEventListener("hashchange", function () {
  window.scrollTo(window.scrollX, window.scrollY - 100);
});
```

It's working only without scroll-behavior property.
Is there any solution? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

try replacing the

```
window.scrollTo(...)
```

with

```
document.getElementById('yourElemId').scrollIntoView({behavior: "smooth", block: "end"});
```

the yourElemId is the id of the element with the anchor.

Here is the documentation for [scrollIntoView](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView)

Comment: I have several links to different anchors. How to use it properly?
Also, where is 100px solution there

Comment: I would use the alignToTop property in conjunction with wrapping the scrollable content in a "content container" that is offset on top by 100px. Can't exactly diagnose the problems without seeing your DOM